# How to start a windows application as standard user when logged in from admin user

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests

I am working on automating tests for a windows application. This application behaves different depending whether logged in user has admin privilege or standard user(non-admin) privilege. Majority of my tests are for admin user, however a small subset it for non-admin user too.

So my question is - how to start a windows application with standard user privilege when logged with as admin privilege.

Logging off from admin user and logging back again with from standard user is not an option as it can not be done in my test automation setup.

Comment: Lookup [`psexec -l`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

Comment: Tried it but my application get stuck on splash screen. Will have to dig deeper to figure out why.